# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n$ Closed Form

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n$ Closed Form

I'm a bit stuck on finding the closed form here. I don't think I can use the technique of computing derivatives here directly.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't see how that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(x)=\sum x^{n}$. Then $f'(x)=\sum nx^{n-1}=\frac 1 x \sum nx^{n}$. Also $f''(x)=\sum n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac 1 {x^{2}}\sum n^{2}x^{n}-\frac 1 {x^{2}}\sum nx^{n}$. Use these equations to write down $\sum nx^{n}$ and $\sum n^{2}x^{n}$ in terms of $f(x)$ (which can be computed explicitly). Can you finish now?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n+1) x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^n=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^{n+1})''+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^{n+1})'.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$f_m(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^mx^n
$,
so that
$f_0(x)
=\dfrac1{1-x}
$,
and
$f_1(x)
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$.

I will show that
$$f_m(x)
=\dfrac{(-1)^m-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}f_k(x)}{1-x}
$$
and
$$f_m(x)
=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)
$$

First,
$f_m(x)-xf_m(x)
=(1-x)f_m(x)
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
f_m(x)-xf_m(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^mx^n-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^mx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^mx^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^mx^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^mx^n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)^mx^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^mx^n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}n^k(-1)^{m-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^mx^n-\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^{n}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^{n}\\
&=-(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^{n}+(-1)^{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n})\\
&=-(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}f_k(x)+(-1)^{m}(f_0(x)-1))\\
&=-(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}f_k(x)-(-1)^{m})\\
\end{array}
$

so

$f_m(x)
=\dfrac{(-1)^m-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}f_k(x)}{1-x}
$.

Since
$f_0(x)
=\dfrac1{1-x}
$,
with
$m=1$,
$f_1(x)
=\dfrac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{0}\binom{0}{0}(-1)^{0}f_0(x)}{1-x}
=\dfrac{1-\frac1{1-x}}{1-x}
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$

With
$m=1$,

$\begin{array}\\
f_2(x)
&=\dfrac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{2}{k}(-1)^{2-k}f_k(x)}{1-x}\\
&=\dfrac{1-(f_0(x)-2f_1(x))}{1-x}\\
&=\dfrac{1-\frac1{1-x}+\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}}{1-x}\\
&=\dfrac{(1-x)^2-(1-x)+2x}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{1-2x+x^2-1+3x}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}\\
\end{array}
$

So

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2+2n+1) x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2n x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^n\\
&=f_2(x)+2f_1(x)+f_0(x)\\
&=\dfrac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}+2\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\dfrac1{1-x}\\
&=\dfrac{x(x+1)+2x(1-x)+(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+x+2x-2x^2+1-2x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\\
\text{or, more simply}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}f_2(x)\\
&=\dfrac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\\
\end{array}
$

Here's another recursion for
$f_m(x)$,
suggested by this last computation.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{x}f_m(x)
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^m x^n\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^m x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^m x^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^m x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}n^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}n^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)\\
&=f_m(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$(\dfrac1{x}-1)f_m(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)
$
or
$f_m(x)
=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)
$.

For $m=1$,
$f_1(x)
=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{0}f_0(x)
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$.

For $m=2$,

$\begin{array}\\
f_2(x)
&=\dfrac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{2}{k}f_k(x)\\
&=\dfrac{x}{1-x}(f_0(x)+2f_1(x))\\
&=\dfrac{x}{1-x}(\dfrac1{1-x}+\dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^2})\\
&=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^3}((1-x)+2x)\\
&=\dfrac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n = \sum\limits_{u=0}^{\infty}u^2x^{u-1} = f(x)$$

$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{\infty}ux^{u} = \int f(x)$

$x\sum\limits_{u=0}^{\infty}ux^{u-1} =  \int f(x)$

$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{\infty}x^{u} = \int \frac{1}{x}\int f(x)$

$\frac{1}{1-x} =  \int \frac{1}{x}\int f(x)$

$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{x}\int f(x)$

$\frac{x+1}{(1-x)^3} = f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start writing $$(n+1)^2 x^n=(n^2+2n+1)x^n=n(n-1)x^n+3n x^n+x^n$$So,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}+3x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}$$ that is to say
$$x^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} \right)''+3x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} \right)'+\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} \right)$$